# GLFW with GCC Mingw flags for static doesn't work as documented

Tags: c, opengl, mingw, glfw

I want to learn openGL without relying on IDE configuring for me. But Seems that I have problems with correct flags.
Before setting up Makefile for me it's easier to test with BAT file.
my build.bat

```
set src=main.c
set output=main.exe
set include=%cd%\include
set lib=%cd%\lib

set compailer=gcc
set compFlags=-Wall
set linkFlags=-lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32

%compailer% %src% -o %output% %compFlags% -I %include% -L %lib% %linkFlags%
```

main.c has the same GLFW example code.
In the project folder headers are in `/include/GLFW` and static lib in `/lib` with `libglfw3.a`.

when compiling I have long list of errors

```
D:\Dev\C\OpenGL>gcc main.c -o main.exe -Wall -I D:\Dev\C\OpenGL\include -L D:\Dev\C\OpenGL\lib -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2z12t2.o:main.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `_imp__glClear@4'
D:\Dev\C\OpenGL\lib/libglfw3.a(init.c.obj):init.c:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `__mingw_free'
D:\Dev\C\OpenGL\lib/libglfw3.a(init.c.obj):init.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `__mingw_free'
...
D:\Dev\C\OpenGL\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x2383): undefined reference to `__mingw_free'
D:\Dev\C\OpenGL\lib/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x4c0c): more undefined references to `__mingw_free' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to follow the GLFW build [guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html).

Comment: `-opengl32` -> `-lopengl32`?

Comment: hmm, probably in the last rewrite I did a typo, but that didn't fix it.
Same errors, so I edited the post. But thanks!

Comment: Are you using MinGW-w64 or MInGW?  Are your libraries for the appropriate toolchain?  The simple fact is that whatever you are linking libglfw3.a contains references to `__mingw_free` and nothing you are linking resolves it.  Most likely you have incompatible tool-chain and libraries.  The `@4` at the end of `__imp_glClear`  menas it used the `_stdcall  ` calling convention - perhaps the library version you have does not?

Comment: I have tried several MinGW-w64 versions and regular MinGW with all updates on the toolchain. Maybe you know a specific one that works?

Comment: I just tried versions from llvm-mingw (github releases both i686) and gave different looking error list, but seems the same meaning.    
```warning: failed to compute relocation: IMAGE_REL_I386_REL32, Invalid data was encountered while parsing the file

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: ___mingw_free
>>> referenced by libglfw3.a(init.c.obj):(.text)
>>> referenced by libglfw3.a(init.c.obj):(.text)
>>> referenced by libglfw3.a(init.c.obj):(.text)
>>> referenced 70 more times
```

Comment: It seems like the GLFW libraries weren't built by the same toolchain

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similar problem trying to do the exact same thing (My only difference was no `undefined reference to _imp__glClear@4`, that only appeared when not using `-lopengl32`).
I have fixed all the undefined reference to `__mingw_free` and `__mingw_realloc` by switching the glfw3 flag from `-lglfw3` to `-lglfw3dll`.
I am still learning so I don't know the real reason why this has fixed the problem.

Comment: Might be better to upvote the other answer if you're not sure @Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lmingw32` to your link flags.  That should deal with `__mingw_free` at least I think.

Also `-glut32 -glu32` perhaps.

According to the link you posted `-lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32` are default libraries and need not be specified - should be harmless though.

Comment: -lmingw32 didn't change anything
https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html doesn't say anything about adding another openGL library, but to be sure I added freeGLUT headers in include/GL and libfreeglut_static.a in /lib with added linkFlag -lfreeglut_static.
Didn't change anything.    
`__mingw_free` suggest that problem is with mingw and I have 2 versions that doesn't work (sourceforge and llvm).

Comment: Checking out GLFW readme file I found it contains binaries for MinGW-w64 and MinGW. I installed the w64 version and still no changes (for compiler I gave an absolute path to gcc to be sure).